# figure at the end of page

Tags: graphics, floats, positioning, titles

On a title page I wanna place a certain figure at the end of the page. There are constraints that the figure needs to be x mm away from the page border. I tried to place the figure with the specifier as documented

```
\begin{figure}[placement specifier]
... figure contents ...
\end{figure}
```

but without success. Is there a way to move the figure below the body/footer by keeping the text untouched in the body/footer sections?

Now, the title page has the following structure:

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{figure}
        \vspace{\dimexpr-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep+Xmm}
        \hspace{\dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin+Xmm}
        \includegraphics{img-top.pdf}   
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[!b]    
        \vspace{ ..297mm -XYZmm.. }
        \hspace{\dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin+Xmm}
        \includegraphics{img-bottom.pdf}
    \end{figure}

    \centering
    \vspace*{4.5cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Description \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Title \par}
    \vspace{3cm}
    {\Large\itshape Author \par}
    \vfill
    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}

\end{titlepage}
```

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Note that content will always be set *inside* the text block, which already has the offsets you seem to *calculate*. What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: What should the layout be with your text "at the bottom" together with an "image at the bottom"? Perhaps you can provide a visual of the requirements?

Comment: And maybe you should just omit the floating `figure` environment.

Comment: The document class is:
    `\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage]{report}`
The text should remain within the predefined body. There needs no text to be outside of the body. Only a figure, a logo, needs to be outside, similarly the image on the top left but only on the bottom with a gap of few mm to the page border.

Comment: @TeXnician: you mean the stuff in the squared bracket, i.e. the [!b]? I already tried that, but without success...

Comment: No, I mean the whole environment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As TeXnician mentioned: If you want an image to show up exactly where you want it to be, you should NOT use the `figure`-environment. Additionally: You might want to take a look at the `tikz`-package, it provides the handy `tikzpicture`-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=south east,yshift=XYZcm,xshift=-Xcm] at (current page.south east)
        {\includegraphics[height=8mm]{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{figure}
        \vspace{\dimexpr-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep+Xmm}
        \hspace{\dimexpr-1in-\oddsidemargin+Xmm}
        \includegraphics[height=8mm]{example-image-a}   
    \end{figure}

    \centering
    \vspace*{4.5cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Description \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Title \par}
    \vspace{3cm}
    {\Large\itshape Author \par}
    \vfill
    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

[image: results]

EDIT: You might want to put both images into one or two `tikzpicture`-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-1cm,xshift=1cm] at (current page.north west)
        {\includegraphics[height=8mm]{example-image-a}};
    \node[anchor=south east,yshift=1cm,xshift=-1cm] at (current page.south east)
        {\includegraphics[height=8mm]{example-image-b}};
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \centering
    \vspace*{4.5cm}
    {\scshape\LARGE Description \par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\huge\bfseries Title \par}
    \vspace{3cm}
    {\Large\itshape Author \par}
    \vfill
    % Bottom of the page
    {\large \today\par}

\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect! That was exactly what I was looking for. But, is it not possible to place two different, independent `tikzpictures` with separate nodes?

Comment: @texxie Yes it is possible. See my edit. I just didn't do that because you only had problems placing the bottom picture, so I left the upper one untouched.